# Notmapped property is not supported in LINQ to Entities

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have a ProUser class which has **ProUserContacts** is a notmapped property, I'm using this property to represent the number of contacts were created by specific proUser :

```
        public class ProUser : BaseEntity
        {
            public Guid? UserId { get; set; }
            ...
            [NotMapped]
            public int ProUserContacts { get; set; }
        }
```

And a controller to query then sort proUser list by **ProUserContacts** :

```
    public IEnumerable<WebDataLayer.Models.ProUser> ListAllPaging(string sortBy)
            {
                var proUsers = _proUserService.Filter(p => !p.IsDelete);
                proUsers = proUsers.OrderBy(x => x.JoinedDay);

                foreach (var item in proUsers)
                {
                    item.ProUserContacts = CountProUserContact(item.Id);
                }

                switch (sortBy?.ToLower())
                {
                   case "prousercontact":
                        proUsers = proUsers.OrderBy(x => x.ProUserContacts);
                        break;

                  default:
                        proUsers = proUsers.OrderBy(x => x.Id);
                        break;
                }
             return proUsers;
            }
```

I want to show the proUser List sorted by ProUserContacts but it comes to an error: **The specified type member 'ProUserContacts' is not supported in LINQ to Entities. Only initializers, entity members, and entity navigation properties are supported.** at this line:

```
proUsers = proUsers.OrderBy(x => x.ProUserContacts);
```

I have tried a couple solutions recommended by the same topics but it didn't work then. 
Need your suggestions!!! 
UPDATE: code for _proUserService:this is simply a set of connection to DB using Entity framework

```
internal class ProUserService : EntityService<ProUser>, IProUserService
    {        
        public ProUserService(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork, IGenericRepository<ProUser> repository) : base(unitOfWork, repository)
        {     
        }

        public List<ProUser> GetProUsersByCustomerCode(string customerCode)
        {
            var proUsers = Repository.Filter(x => !x.IsDelete && x.CustomerCode.ToLower().Equals(customerCode.ToLower())).ToList();
            return proUsers;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you send us more information like which line you are getting an error what is there inside countprousercontact method.

Comment: I've just updated it @Justcode

Comment: Can you share the `_proUserService` code please!

Comment: hi, _proUserService is just a class for a set of connection to Database using entity. It works fine with all the properties that included in SQL DB, doesn't work for notmapped property @TanvirArjel. Anyway I've just update the code for _proUserService

Comment: Okay got! This is may be the default behavior of [NotMapped] property not to support `LINQ to Entities` and `LINQ to SQL`

Comment: even though proUsers got materialized, it still represents a query (the query result is not held in proUsers, but rather in the context) and therefore does not support ordering on not mapped fields.

Comment: I got it, do you have any suggestion? @DevilSuichiro

Comment: since proUsers is an IQueryable, it can't hold materialized values - I'd suggest declaring a materialized list before the switch block (List<ProUser> proUsersMat = null;), assigning its value in the switch block (with .ToList(), also before ordering on the not mapped field) and returning it instead of the IQueryable.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seem coming from `[NotMapped]` attribute set at this property:

```
[NotMapped]
public int ProUserContacts { get; set; }
```

As a consensus, you cannot use any properties that are not mapped as column name in database inside LINQ to Entities query directly because EF doesn't know how to convert `ProUserContacts` into proper `ORDER BY` SQL statement. You need to either materialize the query first with `AsEnumerable()`/`ToList()` before `OrderBy()`:

```
var prusers = proUsers.ToList().OrderBy(x => x.ProUserContacts);
```

or using encapsulation by create an `IQueryable` extension method to be used as substitute of direct `OrderBy`:

```
public class ProUserVM
{
    public int ProUserContacts { get; set; }
}

public static IQueryable<ProUserVM> OrderByContacts(this IQueryable<ProUser> prousers)
{
    return proUsers.Select(x => new ProUserVM
    {
        // other properties
        ProUserContacts = CountProUserContact(item.Id)
    }).OrderBy(x => x.ProUserContacts);
}

// usage
proUsers = proUsers.OrderByContacts();
```

or remove `[NotMapped]` attribute and make the column name based from the property name.

Reference:

[Computed Properties and Entity Framework](https://daveaglick.com/posts/computed-properties-and-entity-framework)

Comment: He has already materialized the query first with AsEnumerable()/ToList() before OrderBy()  in service class. Please check it.

Answer (score 0):

It means that the LINQ query can not be evaluated and translates to the equivalent database query, so first, you must load data to the client-side evaluation by calling `AsEnumerable()` or `ToList()` then do whatever you want to do with `NotMapped` property:

```
proUsers = proUsers.OrderBy(x => x.JoinedDay);
proUsers = proUsers.ToList().OrderBy(x => x.ProUserContacts);
```

read more about client vs server  evaluation:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/client-eval